# Linux: Should I resist temptation to delete files in /tmp?

Tags: filesystems, file-management, temporary-files

I sometimes look at the `/tmp` directory with all those files taking up disk space, and think "*maybe I should go in there and do something about it.*"

On the other hand, in my 10+ years of Linux use, I have never had a disk fill to the rim and need manual intervention. So something somewhere is cleaning house for me (?). So maybe I should step back from the chalupa and let things ride.

This Q is of particular concern to me as I've been burned before by overly aggressive tinkering with system files, some of which turn out to be actually be very important. For example, circa 1999, I fell for the "hidden server" hoax:

> if your Windows 98 has a hidserve.exe file, delete it right away, it is spying on you

Yep, had to do a factory restore after that one. Who knew that hidserve.exe was actually *"Human Interface Device Service"* ... a critical process that runs your keyboard and mouse?

So,

1. Should  I stop obsessing at `/tmp`?
2. Who, what, when process is `/tmp` being emptied so I don't have to worry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Normally the `/tmp` directory is cleaned on boot** – either by the boot process removing all files, or just by being entirely in-memory (many Linux distributions now mount a `tmpfs` on /tmp, so the files don't get stored on disk in the first place).

So if you've rebooted a few times and it's *still* full, might be time to review your configuration.

**Old files *might* get cleaned up while the system is running**, but this depends on your OS.

For example, all Linux distros based on *systemd* periodically delete files modified more than 10 days ago, via "systemd-tmpfiles-clean.{timer,service}".

Some other systems might do the same using `tmpwatch`, but this is rarely installed by default.

**It is generally safe to remove files in `/tmp` that haven't been used for a while,** with the exception of "special" files like sockets. Another exception is "lockfiles" such as `/tmp/.X0-lock`.

There is also **another temporary file location, `/var/tmp`**, which is meant for large and/or long-lived files, therefore it is specifically *not* cleaned upon reboot, and if the OS performs periodic clean-up, then `/var/tmp` usually has a much longer expiry than `/tmp`. However, if you're running out of space, then it is usually safe to delete most things in it as well.

Comment: +1 Didn't know these were cleaned on reboot by the OS. I thought each process was doing this individually. I would point out that sometimes you WILL want to delete lock files and sockets but not because of space concerns. An example I've ran into is if you are using a package manager and it crashes (or is killed) while running. The only way you can get that working again will be to remove the lock file.

Comment: @krowe: It's both. A program is supposed to clean up its own temporary files when it stops needing them. But it might crash before doing so, or it might 'forget' to clean up, so most operating systems that have `/tmp` also clean it on boot and/or periodically.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. I put in some of the temps, and 'forgot' to clean them out. I didn't know a reboot was the cleaner--I reboot rarely, that explains the accumulation of my own mess.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a system executable is much different than deleting a data file such as those stored in `/tmp`.    I've never had much problem with the `/tmp` directory getting very big on my systems (at least after I bounce the deamon which created a big-ish tmp file) but the software you use could make things much different for you. In general, I'd say that deleting temporary files can cause, at worst, temporary problems. Furthermore, I assume that you're using an ext file system so any files in use aren't really going to get deleted until whatever is using them is done with them. This should therefore be perfectly safe. If it does break something then I'd report that as a bug.